# How to retrieve a specific object with Parse.Query

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using Parse to create a WebApp and I am trying to get an instance of an object `Product`with this code:

```
getProduct: function() {
   var productClass = Parse.Object.extend("Product");
   var query = new Parse.Query(productClass);
   var result = query.get(productId, {
       success: function(object) {
          console.log(object.get("productName"));
       },
       error: function(object, error) {
           ...
       }
   });
   return result;
}
```

I get a:

```
result.get is not a function
```

Printing the object only, I realized that I do not get a `Product`, I get this in the console (Safari):

```
[Log] Object (views.js, line 269)
_rejected: false
_rejectedCallbacks: Array[0]
_resolved: true
_resolvedCallbacks: Array[0]
_result: Arguments[1]
__proto__: Object
```

I tried many ways, but I am not able to retrieve a `Product` object and its attributes. What am I doing wrong?

#### EDIT

I am adding my `Products View`:

```
window.app.Products = Parse.View.extend({

    template: _.template($('#products-template').html()),

    el: $('body'),
    content: $('#content'),

    ...

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.render();
    },

    render: function () {
        $(this.content).html(this.template);
        return this;
    },

    ...

    getUser: function() {
        return Parse.User.current();
    },

    getUserProduct: function() {
        var promise = new Parse.Promise();

        var productClass = Parse.Object.extend("Product");
        var query = new Parse.Query(productClass);
        query.equalTo("objectId", this.getUser().get("product").id);
        query.first().then(function(result) {
            if(result){
                // If result was defined, the object with this objectID was found
                promise.resolve(result);
            } else {
                console.log("Product was not found");
                promise.resolve(null);
            }
        }, function(error){
            console.error("Error searching for Product. Error: " + error);
            promise.error(error);
        });

        return promise;
    },

    setProduct: function() {
        this.getUserProduct().then(function(result) {
            if(result){
                console.log(result.get("productName"));
                var productName = result.get("productName");

            } else {
                console.log("Could not set Product"); 
            }
        }, function(error){
            console.log("Error: " + error);
        });
    }
});
```

I was trying by having a list of parameters and updating them like:

```
info: {
         user: '...',
         product: '...'
      }
```

Then passing it to the `template`:

```
$(this.content).html(this.template(this.info));
```

But I am not able to update `product`.

Comment: Can you firstly try simplifying things a little. Try doing a "query.first() rather than query.get(XX), and verify that you are at least getting the first Product in your Product table.

Comment: Great! I was able to do it with `query.equalTo(...)` and `query.first(...)`, but should I use it instead of `query.get(...)`? What is wrong with it?

Comment: Anyway, I am not able to return the object inside the `query.first()`, so I have to assign it to a global variable or something. Is there a way to return the object directly? Thanks!

Comment: Probably easiest to put your query inside a function which returns a promise. When I get to a computer I'll write up an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I wrote this, I realised that you really aren't saving all that much code by pulling the product search into it's own method. My hope is that it will at least demonstrate to you how to create and call your own custom async methods. For example you may have a query which is much more complex than the current query, or it may perform multiple queries before finding the desired response, in which case it would make sense to pull it into it's own method.

**Get Product Async Method**

This method retrieves the Product with the given `objectID`

```
var getProduct =  function(productId) {
    var promise = new Parse.Promise();

    var Product = Parse.Object.extend("Product");
    var query = new Parse.Query(Product);
    query.equalTo("objectId",productId);
    query.first().then(function(result){
        if(result){
            // If result was defined, the object with this objectID was found
            promise.resolve(result);
        } else {
            console.log("Product ID: " + productId + " was not found");
            promise.resolve(null);
        }
    }, function(error){
            console.error("Error searching for Product with id: " + productId + " Error: " + error);
            promise.error(error);
    });

    return promise;
}
```

**Calling Method**

An example of a simple method which calls the above method.

```
var myMethod = function(){
    var productID = "12345678";

    getProduct(productID).then(function(result){
        if(result){
            console.log(result.get("productName"));
            var productName = result.get("productName");
            var productPrice = result.get("productPrice"); 
            // Now that you have some relevant information about your product
            // you could render it out to an Express template, or use this
            // value in a calculation etc. 
        } else {
            console.log("Product with objectId: " + productID + " was not found"); 
        }
    }, function(error){
        console.log("Error: " + error);
    });

}
```

**Notes**

- As these methods are asynchronous, there is no real data being
  returned in the 'return value' (the method returns a promise).
  Instead we return the relevant data as a result of the promise (where
  you see `promise.resolve(XXX)`)
- It doesn't make any sense to have a
  mutable global variable in this Node.js style architecture.

Comment: Ok. With this I am starting to understand this `Parse.Promise` thing. The problem is that I am still not able to get the `product` itself. Maybe this is not a Parse problem, I am not sure. I mean, instead of `console.log(...)` the `product`, I want to return it and use it; say, I want to use its attributes to show them in a page. I still can't do that.

Comment: In the example method above, where I have `console.log(object.get("productName"))`, you actually have the `product`. You can access all the attributes as you did with your example result.get("productName"). If you wanted to render this in a page, if this was client-side javascript, you could modify a HTML element with the value of the product. If this was server side javascript, and you were using the express framework, you could render that value out to a template.

Comment: @makeMonday Is this server side code, or browser based code, that you are looking to implement?

Comment: I just started with Parse so it is still a bit confusing. I am trying to load a `View` and I wanted it to have two parameters `user` and `product` (I'm working with only one product now, but my idea is to have a "list"), so I can show it in the page like `User: ...... ; Product: ......`. I am probably doing it wrong, because I am trying to get it a the `View` and rendering it, but maybe I might want to do it client-side?

Comment: @makeMonday Server side is fine, and potentially easy. Does this mean you are using the Express framework? Do you have any other sample code you can include in your initial question? I could show you how to incorporate code into a view, but I have no idea what approach you are currently using, so I might be pointing you down the wrong path.

Comment: I am using Parse with Parse.js (plus jquery and underscore). I will add my `View` in the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72239/discussion-between-ardrian-and-makemonday).